# Collision with object on another layer isn't working in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I have two box colliders in my scene. I am basically manipulating one and the other is stationary and just on the default layer and it also has a rigidbody attached. The other object I am mostly rotating and for some reason it rotates right through the other object. It is on another layer but, I have checked the layer collision matrix and all of the boxes are checked so I'm not sure why the collision isn't happening. Is there a reason for this?

I am Rotating it with `transform.Rotate`. Neither of the colliders have the isTrigger selected. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Added this to show implementation of `rigidbody.MoveRotation`

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Y) && !colliding)
    {
        if (rigidBody == null)
        {
            rigidBody = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
            rigidBody.useGravity = false;
            rigidBody.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;
        }
        rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, .5f, 0);
        rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidBody.rotation * rot );
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.I) && !colliding)
    {
        if (rigidBody == null)
        {
            rigidBody = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
            rigidBody.useGravity = false;
            rigidBody.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;
        }
        rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, -.5f, 0);
        rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidBody.rotation * rot);
    }

    else if (colliding)
    {
        rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidBody.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(rot));
    }
}
```

Comment: do they collide at all under any circumstance? or is it only during rotation that they do not. also be sure that isKinematic is not checked

Comment: is this 2d or 3d? remember the rigidbody only works with the same dimensions meaning 2d colliders will not collide with 3d colliders. and 2d rigidbodies will not work with 3d collider.

Comment: Also, if you are directly affects the rotation using Transform.rotate, then there won't be collision either.  You need to adjust the rotation using the Rigidbody, not the transform.

Comment: @ryeMoss It is really quite odd. If I check the `isKinimatic` variable I can see the collisions happening as my object flys away haha but when it isn't checked nothing happens. The other object just rotates right through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collisions do not happen if you update the position or rotation of any object through the transform.  You can receive the OnCollision events but you will not get the desire results if you rotate or move using the transform.  Update your code to use the rigidbody for any changes to rotation and position in a fixedUpdate to receive these effects, aka colliding.

Comment: Hmm, I thought this solution would work, however after testing it out, I still get the same result using `rigidbody.MoveRotation.` The object continues to rotate through the other.

Comment: I ended up just adding a bool to the OnCollisionEnter/Exit and only rotate the object depending on the state it was in.

Comment: @Dtb49 do you mind adding how you are doing the rotation with rigidbody.MoveRotation to your question?  I would like to reproduce it or see if there is something I can catch that could be causing the issue? Also, please make sure your interpolation settings on the rigidbody component is enabled.